# Arduino power source

Tags: power-supply, arduino

I am trying to connect an external power source to the arduino while attaching it to the computer. That is because the way I wired the circuit is so that the components directly connect to the power source, not the 5v pin from the arduino. I connected the power to Arduino via VIN and GND pins. The problem is I need to use the Serial Monitor right now to get some troubleshooting data, but I am worried I am about to blow my Arduino, so could somebody please help?? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without realizing I did this once. I had my external power source Vin powering my nano, and needed to troubleshoot my code really quick so I plugged the IDE through USB to PC as I normally would.

I unplugged my external source after realizing this but everything worked and I had no problems,I did use Serial Monitor while debugging and no problem.

I want to think the AT328 has some kind of command although I never found it in the datasheet.

regards.